# How to get all cells value of Jquery Datatable?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, datatables

I'm building a school project, for attendance I'm using jquery datatable. see below image

```
                            jquery datatable records
```

[image]

What I want is to get all cells value (third column is a dropdown) in a variable and pass it to a web method using ajax call.

Comment: All cell values in a single string variable or in different variables?

Comment: I'd prefer single var. which is better?

Comment: Its totally depends on your further code logic how you will going to consume it

Comment: In what way you want to get the values? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This may steer you in the right direction. I'm only getting the selected row values with this example, but I'm sure you can massage it to make it give you what you want. Use the Api calls, they're easier to work with:

```
        var identifier = $('#amt').attr('data-id'); //get id for row using data attribute

        var table = $('#searchTable').dataTable();
            var rows = table.fnGetNodes();
            for (var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++) {                    
                var myRow = $('#searchTable').dataTable().fnGetData(rows[r]);
                if (myRow[0] == identifier) {
                    partId = myRow[5];
                    desc = myRow[6];
                    break;
                }
            }
```